# rmi registry: best way to assure there's one running?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm missing something about the difference between

1. starting rmiregistry at the command prompt (separately from whatever Java process is running a server that implements an RMI interface)
2. having the server call [`LocateRegistry.getRegistry()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#getRegistry%28%29)
3. having the server call [`LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/registry/LocateRegistry.html#createRegistry%28int%29)

I just want my server to register its exported objects with the registry, creating one if there isn't one running already. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but...

```
man rmiregistry
```

says:

> The methods of the java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry class are used to
>   get a registry operating on the **local host** or local host and port.

otherwise you have:

> The URL-based methods of the java.rmi.Naming class operate on a registry and can be used to look up a **remote object on any host** and on the local host

So I guess that's the important difference. Other thing is SecurityManager and policies.

Comment: upvoting because you answered the question, but yeah, this Q is so old that I remember essentially nothing about RMI and can't evaluate it any further.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used to do it, not sure if it is the right way though :/. I also had to mess around with policy files, so if this gives you trouble as well (the security manager part) you must create a policy file and use it.

```
    try
            {
                try
                {
                    java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
                }

               catch (java.rmi.server.ExportException e) {  /*  */  }

                System.setSecurityManager(new java.rmi.RMISecurityManager());
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099);
                registry.rebind(...);
            }

            catch (Exception e) {   /*  */  }
    }
```